# PHP inserting array into an object

Tags: php, arrays, object

I am trying to inject an array into an object but it's just not working. This is what I am doing:

1) Get a specific `Match` record from the database

2) Get all the `Player` records from the database that are associated with that match

3) **Add them players to the `Match` object**

Code:

```
$matchQuery = "SELECT * FROM matches where new = 1 order by date asc limit 1";
$matchResult = mysql_query($matchQuery,$link) or die('Errant query:  '.$matchQuery);

/* create one master array of the records */
$matches = array();
if(mysql_num_rows($matchResult)) {
    while($match = mysql_fetch_assoc($matchResult)) {

        $playersQuery = "SELECT p.* FROM match_players mp
                        LEFT JOIN players p on p.id = mp.player_id
                        WHERE mp.match_id = '$match->id'";

        $playerResult = mysql_query($playersQuery,$link) or die('Errant query:  '.$playersQuery);

        $players = array();
        if(mysql_num_rows($playerResult)) {
            while($player = mysql_fetch_assoc($playerResult)) {
                $match->players[] = $player; //<-- This doesn't seem to work
            }
        }
        $matches[] = $match;
    }
}
```

The objects within `Match` are being spat out, BUT, the `Players` are not.

Comment: Is there more code? Did you instantiate your objects?

Comment: `$players = array();` doesn't appear to be used.

Comment: why are you doing `$players = array();`  it serves no purpose?

Comment: Please, clear up this code. Remove irrelevant parts and leave just important ones. Also explain important parts of code, for example, start with what that $match (object) comes from, what's purpose of $players array, etc. Nobody can guess what you have server-side and what's up onto your mind. From someone with 1000+ rep I really expect some experience in writing questions.

Comment: I disagree with you. I don't think there's any further need to explain what the objects do since in my opinion, it's self explanatory. Originally, I only pasted the code which was erroneous but @Scopey asked for more, and I gave more. Two answers were given immediately that partially fixed the issue, so again, I disagree with what you're saying.

Comment: Hmm, so you got $match from mysql_fetch_assoc() which, by the way, returns array, string or boolean false and still don't see that no one of these results is an object even you try to use them that way? Which part of this I'm wrong with?

Comment: @Wh1T3h4Ck5 Go troll somewhere else. Question has been answered twice already.

Comment: I'll go where I want to go. It's nothing wrong with the answers, your question is problem!

Comment: If the question was answered immediately by two people without any notion of confirming what my question is actually portraying, then the question is fine. The above example is a dead, dead, dead simple example of a PHP connection. You don't even need to know what the $match variable does. Just because I haven't explained every nook and corner of the code, doesn't mean that it's a bad question. I don't need to get an encyclopedia out and explain every single line of code. Get it? Now Go, Troll, Somewhere, Else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$match` is an array, the result of the deprecated `mysql_fetch_assoc()`. So `$match->players[] = $player;` is not going to work.

If there is no `players` key in the sql result, you can add it to the array:

```
$match['players'][] = $player;
```

Otherwise you would have to use a different key.

Another problem is your query in the loop: You use `$match->id` and that should be `$match['id']` as `$match` is an array.

By the way, doing sql queries in a loop is never a good idea, you should try to get your results in one query joining the different tables.

Comment: For some reason, the players array you've defined above is null. It's not getting the players. If I run the query right in the database, it works.

Comment: @Subby You assume that `$match` is an object but it is not. In your query (the one in the loop) you use `$match->id` and that should be `$match['id']`.

Comment: PERFECT! @jeroen For President!

Comment: If I ever come to Peru, I shall buy you a the finest cup'o'coffee that Peru has to offer.

Answer (score 1):

```
$match["players"] = array();

while($player = mysql_fetch_assoc($playerResult)) {
   $match["players"][] = $player;
}
```